# Clojure - function that returns a vector of vector

Tags: clojure

I want to write a function that when you pass in a vector as an argument, it returns the iterations of the vector ie

- If you pass in [1], it returns [1]
- If you pass in [1 2], it returns [[1 2] [2 1]]
- If you pass in [1 2 3], it returns [[1 2 3] [2 3 1] [3 1 2]]
  etc

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could look something like that:

```
user> (defn its [items]
        (let [c (count items)]
          (if (<= c 1)
            items
            (->> items
                 cycle
                 (partition c 1)
                 (take c)
                 (mapv vec)))))
#'user/its

user> (its [])
;;=> []

user> (its [1 2])
;;=> [[1 2] [2 1]]

user> (its [1 2 3])
;;=> [[1 2 3] [2 3 1] [3 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The function `permutations` in https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/ can be used for that

Example from the Readme.md:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo]))

; PERMUTATIONS
; all the unique arrangements of items
=> (combo/permutations [1 2 3])
([1 2 3] [1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 1 2] [3 2 1])

; Note that permutations intelligently handles duplicate items
=> (combo/permutations [1 1 2])
([1 1 2] [1 2 1] [2 1 1])
```

Comment: As far as i understand, op doesn't need permutations, he rather needs cycled values. That means [1 3 2], [2 1 3], [2 3 1] and [3 2 1] are false results.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is to cut the input in two pieces and join the two pieces in reverse order (first piece after second piece).

So you need a function to calculate rotations of a vector:

```
(defn rotations [v]
```

You want to work with a vector (for fast random access) and you will also need the size of the vector.

```
(let [v (vec v)
      n (count v)]
```

You need to iterate through every locations in the input where the cutting should be made:

```
  (for [i (range n)]
```

Then cut the vector on the `i`-th position and merge them in reverse order:

```
    (into (subvec v i n) (subvec v 0 i))
```

Oh, and do not forget to close the parentheses!

```
)))
```